# Scroll to child Recyclerview item in Nested Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

### Context

I have a nested Recyclerview like the following sketch shows you:

[image: Sketch of my nested Recyclerview]

In the drawing you can see a RecyclerView, which in turn holds one RecyclerView each as item.

### Question

My question now is: How can I get the outer, parent Recyclerview scroll to a position of one of the child RecyclerViews. In the drawing I marked you Content pos 5 as my target position for example the Child RecyclerView 2.

### What I already found out

One approach I've been thinking about was using `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)` on the parent RecyclerView, then just scroll to the position of the child RecyclerView 2 and then have the offset as the size of the list of items in the Child RecyclerView. But how can I get the size when the view isn't even inflated?

I would be very happy if one of you could give me some help that also ran into this problem of scrolling to a position of the child RecyclerView in such a nested Recyclerview.

Comment: can you explain the reason for using nested recycler view?

Comment: @bk7 yes, for sure. With using such an implementation I can use sections. Each item of the parent RecyclerView defines a section and a recyclerview of a section holds the actual content of the respective section. The sections are not fixed and can be created by the user. So I cannot hardcore them into the layout.

Comment: I have same issue. have you find any solution? @J.Hegg

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, i caculate the total scrolling length including the section header (Fixed height) and child recycleview's item, you my ask the question of "how can I get the size when the view isn't even inflated or draw?". you can use view.measure() to get cotent item's measured height:

```
int widthMeasureMode = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureMode = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
contentView.measure(widthMeasureMode, heightMeasureMode);
int measureHeight = contentView.getMeasureHeight();
```

the need to scroll distantce: account all the single item's measured height, and plus all the section header's height.

for example, you need to scorll to the second section, and make this section's second child content view scroll to the screen top, suppose the first section has 6 content view, the total scroll distance is :
2 section's height plus 7 item content' height.

In fact, you could get and save all the child's absolute Y position on the screen Coordinate. so you can scroll to any child content in nested recycleview.

recycleView.scrollBy(0,  needToScrollDistance);

Comment: This does not explain how to actually scroll

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).